# PHP/mysqli, Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, arrays, out-of-memory

This is part of my script:

```
echo "\n" . memory_get_usage(false) ;   // memory = 3697576
$ids = array() ;
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $ids[] = $row[0] ;
}
echo "\n" . memory_get_usage(false) ;   // memory = 4319960
echo "\n" . sizeof ($ids) ;         // size of $ids = 3500 => 150 bytes/element in $ids
```

When I run the same with a much larger $ids (1 million elements), I get the infamous:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

this confirms the 150 bytes/element.

In the MySQL database, the id field is INT(UNSIGNED) which means 4 bytes/element and, in PHP (Centos 64 bit), I guess that a $ids element only needs 8 bytes.

So why these 150 bytes for an id ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Read, learn and understand](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)... this article was written for PHP5, and PHP7 is much more efficient in its memory usage for arrays, but they are still not memory efficient.... you are not simply storing an int value when you store it in an array

Comment: Another viewpoint is to understand why you want to hold a million id's.  What are you doing with them?  Understand how to efficiently process data is a vital part of writing good software.

Comment: As to what you can do about it - fetch stuff in a loop bit by bit in order to not clog up your memory.